# C++ How to overload += operator for class using map?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have `Poly` class that contains a polynomial in a map. How can I overload the `+=` operator for it so that it adds together multipliers with the same exponential?

example:

`4x²+2x+7` is contained as `(2, 4), (1, 2), (0, 7)`

```
class Poly {
    typedef std::map<int, int> Values;
    Values m_values;
public:
    typedef Values::const_reverse_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef Values::reverse_iterator iterator;
    int operator[](int exp) const;
    Poly& operator+=(Poly const& b);
    Poly& operator-=(Poly const& b);
};

Poly& Poly::operator+=(Poly const& b) {
    // ???
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Btw keeping multipliers in vector would be significantly more efficient by memory and performance. In theory it could use more memory though, but that is very unlikely.

Comment: I recommend restructuring your program.  Create a `Term` class, which has coefficient and exponent.  A `Polynomial` would be a container of `Term`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews what kind of container? Perhaps a map?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Any kind of container, usually the "one dimensional", such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::array` or a custom container.  One cannot guarantee the order of the terms when using a `std::map`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Poly& Poly::operator+=(Poly const& b) {
    for (Values::const_iterator iter = b.m_values.begin(), end = b.m_values.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
        Values::iterator found = m_values.find(iter->first);
        if (found != m_values.end()) {
            found->second += iter->second;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}

Poly& Poly::operator-=(Poly const& b) {
    for (Values::const_iterator iter = b.m_values.begin(), end = b.m_values.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
        Values::iterator found = m_values.find(iter->first);
        if (found != m_values.end()) {
            found->second -= iter->second;
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```